# Event fires only when autopost=false in asp.net 4.5 VS 2013 with Ajaxcontroltoolkit 16.1.1.0

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working in asp.net 4.5 in vs 2013 with Ajaxcontroltoolkit 16.1.1.0. I am having a a gridview with rating control. Rating control OnChanged event fires only when `autopost=false`; if I set it to true it does not. When I use `response.redirect` it gives a exception:

> response.redirect cannot be called in a page callback

I searched for this and used:

```
Response.RedirectLocation = Page.ResolveUrl("~/stage2scoringsheet.aspx?InnovationId=" + InnovId);
```

But the page is not post backing. I have checked removing all my update panels but it does not work. When I click on rating some calculation happens and should display in `lbl_TotalFinalScore`. Currently calculation is done ans stored in db but not able to display in `lbl_TotalFinalScore` when rating is selected. If close the page and come back again it displays.

Below is C# code.

```
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="decla">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="rating-eva">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
    <a onclick="guidlines()" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="imgs/ED.gif" width="188" height="32" border="0" /></a>
   </div>
   <asp:GridView ID="gvScore" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" OnRowDataBound="gvScore_RowDataBound" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="InnovationId,Submittedby">
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <div class="row ra" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="sect-eva">
   <div class="eval-icon">
   <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="eval-head">
   <h4>Innovation</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="eval-rating">
   <h6 class="pull-left">Your Rating
   <br>
   <a class="eval-help" data-toggle="modal" href="#innovation">Help Text?</a>

   </h6>
   <div class="ratin-main">
   <%-- <img src="rating.png">--%>
   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
   <itemtemplate>
   <ajax:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CurrentRating='<%# Bind("Innovation") %>' StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed" Tag="10" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1"></ajax:Rating>
   <asp:Label ID="lbl_Innovation" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Rate Innovation"></asp:Label>
   <%--  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Score" ErrorMessage="Rate Innovation" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ClientValidate" ForeColor="red"></asp:CustomValidator>--%>
   </itemtemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <h6>
   <asp:Label ID="lblR1NotRated" CssClass="rating_Not" runat="server" Text="Not Rated" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="lblR1Rated" CssClass="rating" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="eval-comm">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_InnovationComments" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="eval-textarea" placeholder="Enter Comments if applicable" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InnovationComments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="sect-eva">
  <div class="eval-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-wheelchair" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
   <div class="eval-head">
  <h4>Social Impact</h4>
  </div>
   <div class="eval-rating">
  <h6 class="pull-left">Your Rating<br>
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="eval-help" href="#social">Help Text?</a>

  </h6>
  <div class="ratin-main">
  <%--<img src="rate.png">--%>
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
  <itemtemplate>
   <ajax:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CurrentRating='<%# Bind("SocialImpact") %>' StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" OnChanged="Rating2_Changed" Tag="10" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior2">
  </ajax:Rating>
  <asp:Label ID="lbl_SocialImpact" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Rate Social Impact"></asp:Label>
   <%--  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Score" ErrorMessage="Rate Social Impact" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator2_ClientValidate" ForeColor="Red">
   </asp:CustomValidator>--%>
   </itemtemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <h6>
   <asp:Label ID="lblR2NotRated" CssClass="rating_Not" runat="server" Text="Not Rated" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="lblR2Rated" CssClass="rating" runat="server" Text="Rated" Visible="false"></asp:Label></h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="eval-comm">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SocialImpactComments" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="eval-textarea" placeholder="Enter Comments if applicable" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SocialImpactComments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="sect-eva">
    <div class="eval-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="eval-head">
    <h4>Team</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="eval-rating">
    <h6 class="pull-left">Your Rating
    <br>
    <a class="eval-help" data-toggle="modal" href="#team1">Help Text?</a>

    </h6>
    <div class="ratin-main">
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
    <itemtemplate>
    <%-- <img src="rate.png">--%>
    <ajax:Rating ID="Rating3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CurrentRating='<%# Bind("Team") %>' StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" OnChanged="Rating3_Changed" Tag="10" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior3" CssClass="err-msg">
    </ajax:Rating>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Team" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Rate Team"></asp:Label>
    <%-- <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Score" ErrorMessage="Rate Team" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator3_ClientValidate" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:CustomValidator>--%>
    </itemtemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <h6>
    <asp:Label ID="lblR3NotRated" CssClass="rating_Not" runat="server" Text="Not Rated" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblR3Rated" CssClass="rating" runat="server" Text="Rated" Visible="false"></asp:Label></h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="eval-comm">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_TeamComments" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="eval-textarea" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Comments if applicable" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.TeamComments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="sect-eva">
    <div class="eval-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please also read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok, I will wait. @halfer